# Google App Engine, Permalinks and CSS

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been working through the Udacity Web Enginnering course and have got stuck, on one of the homeworks.

I've created a basic blog that allows me to create posts and displays them on the main page. Furthermore, each time a post is created a permalink is generated and the page displayed. However, while my HTML renders fine, all CSS is lost. The stylesheet is certainly referenced in the source returned from the server, but is not displayed.

The same CSS file (stlye.css) is used successfully however elsewhere.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
blog:
    - app.yaml
    - main.py
templates:
    - index.html
    - newpost.html
    - styles.css
stylesheets
    - styles.css
```

Here's my applications code:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

# Defines the database model
class Post(db.Model):
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

# Base handler class with utility functions
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_environment.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Blog(Handler):
    def get(self):
        posts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post ORDER BY created DESC")
        self.render('index.html', posts = posts)

# Render a single post
class Permalink(Handler):
    def get(self, post_id):
        post = Post.get_by_id(int(post_id))
        self.render("index.html", posts = [post])

# Submission form
class NewPost(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("newpost.html")

    def post(self):
        subject = self.request.get("subject")
        content = self.request.get("content")

        if subject and content:
            post = Post(subject = subject, content = content)
            key = post.put()
            self.redirect("/blog/%d" % key.id())    
        else:
            error = "Something went wrong. We need both a subject and content"
            self.render("newpost.html",subject=subject, content=content, error=error)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog', Blog), ('/newpost', NewPost), ('/blog/(\d+)', Permalink)], debug=True)
```

And my app.yaml:

```
application: 20-khz-udacity
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /blog/(\d+)
  script: main.app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

And, finally, the template used for the the index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />
  <title>CS 253 Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/blog" class="main-title">Ray's Blog</a>
  <div class="age">Queried 104973 seconds ago</div>
  <div id="content">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-title">{{post.subject}}</div>
        <div class="post-date">{{post.created}}</div>
        <pre class="post-content">{{post.content}}</pre>
    </div>  
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the actual app can be found here:
http://20-khz-udacity.appspot.com/blog/

Does anybody have an idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post your project structure, app.yaml, and the relevant code of the template. If the css is not rendering the most probable cause is because the url is wrong, check that it was downloaded using the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: In the directory structure section, you list `styesheets` as one of your directories. That's just a typo, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the answer may be as simple as making the link to the CSS absolute rather than relative.

When you say this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />`

You are telling the browser that the stylesheet address is relative to the current page, so it's probably trying to load `http://?????.???/blog/stylesheets/styles.css/`

If you make it absolute, by adding a leading slash to the href,

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css" />`

it would try to load `http://?????.???/stylesheets/styles.css/` and that is what your app.yaml is configured to serve.